# How to reset only the setups of a mock in Mock 4.12?

Tags: c#, moq

Whenever I call .Reset in any mock using Moq 4.12, it explicitly reset everything about the mock, from setups to event handlers.

```
moqActionFactory.Reset();
```

How can I reset only the configured setups? I see no methods or properties (like Invocations.Clear) to do so.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible.

`Reset()` is implemented in [MockExtensions.cs](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/src/Moq/MockExtensions.cs) as:

```
public static void Reset(this Mock mock)
{
    mock.ConfiguredDefaultValues.Clear();
    mock.Setups.Clear();
    mock.EventHandlers.Clear();
    mock.Invocations.Clear();
}
```

So it would appear simple, we just have to call `Clear()` on the `Setups` collection! But that is defined in [Mock.cs](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/src/Moq/Mock.cs) as:

```
internal abstract SetupCollection Setups { get; }
```

And furthermore [SetupCollection](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/master/src/Moq/SetupCollection.cs) is also internal.

So unless there is some reflection wizardry that can be done here, there appears to be no supported way to do this from looking at the Moq source.

Comment: what a bummer, but thanks anyways, I expected moq to provide a more granular way of controlling its properties, will write an issue in case they can provide this

Comment: @OscarGuillamon perhaps you could submit a pull request to them? Literally you would just need to add another method to MockExtensions that only calls mock.Setups.Clear() and name it ResetSetups.

Comment: oh, thanks for the suggestion, didn't think about that

Comment: I've developed the code necessary to provide this behaviour, hope they accept the pull request

Comment: 2 years later and still nope.  This sure would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

These days, you can remove a specific setup using `SetupRemove()`.
e.g., `mock.SetupRemove(_ => _.FooMethod(It.IsAny<int>()));`

Comment: This only works for events that have been attached with `mock.SetupAdd(...);`